# how do i prevent mySql injection

Tags: php, mysql, code-injection

i need to know about how to prevent our database from sql injection, i read many blog and answer on internet but could not justify which way i should prefer or best.
just like for mysql:

```
 mysqli:
mysql_real_escape_string.
```

or using

```
Using PDO:
```

i know if user something inserting in database it becomes vulnerable to SQL injection, and i generally use this code for insertion:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysql_select_db("test",$con);
$foo=$_POST['foo'];
$boo=$_POST['boo'];

$insert="insert into table set foo='$foo',boo='$boo'";
```

so what should i do for prevent my database injection..... any idea would be appreciated highly..
Thanx in advance

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons

Comment: this question has been asked "i cant even count" number of times.. do a quick search on google or better stackoverflow. Use `PDO`. you will get in built security.

Comment: +1 for great guideness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the below code, very well, then translating it to PDO would be like:

FROM SQL Code:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysql_select_db("test",$con);
$foo=$_POST['foo'];
$boo=$_POST['boo'];
$insert="insert into table set foo='$foo',boo='$boo'";
```

TO PDO Code:

```
<?php
$con= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=xxxx', 'username', 'password')
$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO Table (foo, boo) VALUES (?,?)');
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['foo'], $_POST['boo']))
```

PDO helps you to prepare the query, then execute unlike mysql which does all together at the same instance.

Now, `$con = new PDO()` is very much like, `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` it opens the connection.

`$stmt` is a variable, which holds the returned query much like the `$result` in `$result = mysql_query()`
next is `execute()` this actually executes your code, meaning all your sql queries are prepared then executed, one after the other making sql injection almost impossible, to be.

this is a basic and good tutorial if you want to learn about PDO
http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: so first i hvae to learn PDO imlementation

Comment: @Jack yes, this is a very good tutorial http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: @Jack you can also do a safe query in mysql but wont be a good option just because its deprecated you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189 for more information

Comment: @NullPointer: So nice Description. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You should use PDO for several reasons:

1) It has parameterized querys so no sql injection

2) PHP's mysql functions are depreciated as of PHP 5.5.0

Comment: Don't worry there is always someone to upvote :)

Comment: Yeah I know, just it is a perfectly legit answer

Comment: we can not say its perfactly legit ... i mean you can atleast tell whats worn in that code ...i know mysql_* is deprecated .. and mysql_* are as safe as pdo or mysqli there is no question about that .. but on the top they are deprecated  and that it

Answer (score 1):

by using [stored procedures](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx) instead of direct queries , you may prevent your system from sql injections

Comment: so you proc up a bunch of mysql_ commands and feed in user supplied data ?

Comment: so whats bad in it? can you explain the reason of your downvote?

Comment: because you didnt change anything .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239905/am-i-immune-to-sql-injections-if-i-use-stored-procedures

Comment: so i am going to retype the crux of the reference i provided in this little box ?

Comment: but you should write the relevant part.I am not DB expert but i just share my knowledge as much I know. Anyway its your right to vote down if you think that I am wrong :) goodluck

Comment: if the user-supplied data as parameters are not sanitized you have effectively said this: what you used to call via inline sql, you are passing off to a stored proc to perform exactly like before. nothing has changed, except a false sense of security.